# Systemd : Run a Python Script At Startup (virtualenv)

Tags: python, systemd, daemon, virtualenv

I have a python script that I normally run it with this command:

```
(environment) python run.py
```

I want to run this script at start. (I'm using ubuntu) Here is my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle

ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/space/run.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

BTW, I couldn't run this script, but I could run any script that is not inside environment. How can I run a python script at startup (virtualenv)?

```
sudo systemctl status user_sent
● user_sent.service - Mail Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user_sent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since xxxxx 16:30:20 MSK; 3s ago
Process: 3713 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python run.py (code=exited,   status=200/CHDIR)
Main PID: 3713 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

Comment: What say logs and status?

Comment: I have edited my question. Many thanks @FedericoSierra

Comment: The script is runnig outside venv, `/usr/bin/python run.py`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211115/how-to-enable-a-virtualenv-in-a-systemd-service-unit and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278188/systemd-how-to-start-stop-python-script-that-should-run-in-background-inside-v

Comment: I did try them. I have to run "python run.py" not "python /user_sent/run.py"

Comment: The python path must point to version inside virtual environment, Eg `/path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python`

Comment: You could setup Environment by starting virtualenv in 'ExecStartPre=' Section

Comment: @rhasti no need for that. It is enough to run python with the full path to the venv like Federico explained.

Comment: The one thing that makes me wonder is this line: `code=exited, status=200/CHDIR`. The script seems to start fine, but something in the script seems to cause an error. What happens if you run `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/space/run.py` as root?

Comment: Try to convert `Type=idle` to `Type=oneshot`.

Comment: @Daniel this python script only run with "python run.py" from application directory. "WorkingDirectory=/home/user/space
ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python  run.py
Restart=always" doesnt work.

Comment: That was not what I asked.

Comment: yes, they run as root

Comment: That was not what I asked. Please run the full command as root. `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/space/run.py`

Comment: full command run. But the "run.py" must run as "python run.py" not full path.

Comment: full command working with "cd space; /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python run.py"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50369/discussion-between-daniel-and-phpexe).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your unit file is correct. If you want to run any python file under an *venv* you just need to reference the python binary in the *venv* directory like you did with `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle

ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/space/run.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What sticks out is the reason your unit fails: `code=exited, status=200/CHDIR`. This most likely indicates an issue within your script.

If you want to debug that, you would do the following:

1. Run the command you added to `ExecStart=` exactly like that under root to see, if the issue is caused by your script.
2. If that runs without errors, look at the journal with `journalctl -u <unit_name>`. That should give you some more information on issues with your unit.

**Post Scriptum**

Both of the following `[Service]` options work:

```
ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /home/user/space/run.py
```

or

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/space
ExecStart=/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python run.py
```

The only difference is that relative calls in your script run from different directories. So if your script contains a line `open("my_file", "w")`, in the first example it would create a file `/my_file` and the second a file `/home/user/space/my_file`.